# Setting background image to cover all of page in Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, illustrator-cs6

I want to have an image as background in Microsoft Word 2013 (I also tried with Photoshop and AI). I tried the watermark, but it was being difficult and would not cover the page 100%. I also tried the header route and the box with image.

Then I used the image as background, with text over it. It works as expected, except that there is a 1/4" (quarter inch) white margin around the image. **In all 4 methods by the way.**
Same with Adobe.

How can I remove that margin, or is there a better way to set a background image?

(Same problem with PS and AI/CC6)

I use Window 8/MS 2013

Comment: I was told at the MS forum that the little strip around the page is a limitation of the printer (regular printer, not a photo printer).

Comment: For all with the same problem, there are several ways to do this, all with that margin: watermark, header, text box. Set the image as background. Scale to the extent of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The margin you are seeing is the page border. Type in any character or text in the document, you need this to be able to write later, any exciting text will work too. Import the Image and set the text mode to *Behind the text*. Now move the image to the top left corner and scale it over the whole page. You may have to rightclick the image and click *Send to back*. Your printer is propertly not able to print the whole page and you will see the border again, but this is a hardware limit.
I suggest to set the background at the end, to be able to format and write text as always.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have done almost everything, except set the image at the end. In the screen, it works perfectly. When I print, there is that small white margin (quarter inch or so). So I am kind of accepting the hardware issue. In another forum, they told me to use photo printer, which is the right one to print all the way to the limit of the page. I don't have that printer, and I need to send this file to a company, so this is the reason I have spent almost a day on this :(